# Framework for license-key verification (OS X, Cocoa)?

Tags: macos, cocoa, cryptography, elliptic-curve, license-key

First of all, I know about this: [Licensing Technology for OS X applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442078/licensing-technology-for-os-x-applications)

But, since it was posted so long ago, that almost all answers point to dead urls, I think its time for a new question.

I am researching options on frameworks for license-key registration for OSX cocoa apps. I want to know what is out there, that supports Elliptic Curve Cryptography and is released under MIT or something similarly permissive as a license.

Currently, I've found just this (Watchdog): https://github.com/konstantinpavlikhin/Watchdog

But there are no reviews about it, nor does it seem to have much traction at github.

Comment: The Mac App Store :-)

Comment: The App Store makes it hard to release fixes on time and they ask for money before I make any of my app ($100). I decided to follow the lead of successful products such as Sublime Text, which isn't distributed through a store.

Comment: Fair enough - though they provide you with an infrastructure (i.e. you actually get something for your bucks). And spending time to roll your own is costing you money, too - after some fashion..

Comment: Indeed. Still, they get 30% of all sales, yet require additional $100/year... I guess, they will reconsider this soon, but until then, this is the path I choose. And please don't mention the statistical improbability called "being featured by the store".

Answer (score 1):

I use [EllipticLicense](https://github.com/vslavik/ellipticlicense) for ECDSA-based license keys (the link is my fork of an abandoned project). It doesn't do online activation or validation or provide any UI, but it's simple and the validation is cross-platform, which is what I need.

I'm keeping an eye on [DevMate](http://devmate.com) by MacPaw as an all-in-one solution, but they're not out of beta yet.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not what you're asking for - but I can't see the purpose in super-complicated key generating algorithms when users can simply distribute valid keys they've bought from you through the various, well-known means (web sites, offline apps/databases of license codes)..

It might pay off to rather spend the time in developing cool features and building a strong user-community that's *willing* to support your app.

Comment: Well, of course. That's why I am not implementing a lib on my own. And about the distribution of licenses - it will have their personal data in it as a plain text also, such licenses will be blacklisted in future builds.